# `chmod` not working on Dockerfile (macbook)

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile, devops

I'm currently working on a **Dockerfile** that requires me to have permissions to read, write and execute on two specific folders. When it comes time to run the the `chmod` commands, it just fail. I can manually change the permissions once inside the docker container but it doesn't seem to pick it up from the command. This is what it looks like currently:

```
FROM <image-source>
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
USER root
WORKDIR /bla/bla
COPY . .
CMD chmod 777 -R /src/main/*
CMD chmod 777 -R /app/main/*
```

Comment: How are you running the container?  Where do the `/src` and `/app` directories come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Dockerfile can only have **one** `CMD` instruction, which define the command occuring when the container is launched.

Try to replace these lines:

```
CMD chmod 777 -R /src/main/*
CMD chmod 777 -R /app/main/*
```

by:

```
RUN chmod 777 -R /src/main/*
RUN chmod 777 -R /app/main/*
```

In this case, `chmod` commands will occurs when building the image.